# changing default structure in maven for war

Tags: java, maven, war

My project folder structure is different from that of Maven. Can I still use Maven?

If yes ..
I want to use webContent folder instead of webapp .. how can i do that?

i already changed java folder to javaSource using .. can anyone help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have whatever structure you want and still use maven. Just define directory with your web resources.

```
<project>
...
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
          <directory>resource2</directory>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the war plugin usage page: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html

In your case, you'll need to set the warSourceDirectory (in a `<configuration>` tag in the war-`<plugin>` section) like:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```